# Why My Android Webview Is So Slow

Tags: android, webview

I tried some ways to solve the speed problem but the site is loading very very slowly on webview even it opens in 3 seconds in Chrome. What I try is, adding these two lines on my code;

```
mWebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

and adding 
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
to my Manifest file as I found these solutions there. But it's not working. So what is wrong ? Thanks in advice.

onCreateView part of my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mPbar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view_progress);


    mView = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    mImageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    mImageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.big_image_loading);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mImageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).start();
        }
    });
    mView.addView(mImageView);
    mWebview = new WebView(getActivity());
    mWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mWebview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    if(internetAccess()){
        if (mUrl != null) {

            mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
            mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
            mWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
            mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            mWebview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                mWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            mWebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            mWebview.loadUrl(mUrl);



        }
        mView.addView(mWebview);
        mBackBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view_btn_back);
        mFowardBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view_btn_forward);
        mRefreshBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view_btn_refresh);
        mRefreshPbar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        // mShareBtn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view_btn_share);

        mBackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFowardBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRefreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        updateActionView();

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. Problem is not about WebSettings. view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); part is on my onPageFinished function and thats why site is loading so slow. I moved it to onPageStarted function and it works so fast.